# What is the minimum required JSON fields for a logged ERROR to end up in Google Cloud Error Reporting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-logging

The minimum JSON for a [structured error](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/samples/cloudrun-manual-logging) message to be parsed in by google (i.e. be marked as debug/info/error/... in the GCP logs) is `{"severity":"ERROR","message":"hello world"}`. But this error will never pop up in [GCP Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting).

What is the minimum required fields for an error to actually show up in [GCP Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting)?

Comment: The specific use case I have is writing a log message to stdout/stderr on a google cloud run instance. But I do believe that the fields would be the same on other services that ends up in google logs (e.g. google cloud functions and so on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Log an error event that is a text message](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages#log-entry-examples). Of notable important is the `@type` field. If you aren't providing a `stack_trace` then `Error Reporting` is looking for more information in order to group the error.

Answer (score 1):

This will result in a instance in [Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting):

```json
{
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "message": "hello error",
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.devtools.clouderrorreporting.v1beta1.ReportedErrorEvent"
}
```

(severity is not taken into consideration, I managed to get a `INFO` severity "error" into [Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting))

This will also result in a message in [Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting):

```json
{
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "message": "hello error",
  "stack_trace": "goroutine 8 [running]:\nmain.main.func2({0x6f0948, 0xc0000d6000}, 0xc0000b6700)\n\t/app/main.go:42 +0x6c\nnet/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc000045af0?, {0x6f0948?, 0xc0000d6000?}, 0x0?)\n\t/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2109 +0x2f\nnet/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x0?, {0x6f0948, 0xc0000d6000}, 0xc0000b6700)\n\t/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2487 +0x149\nnet/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP({0xc00006d0e0?}, {0x6f0948, 0xc0000d6000}, 0xc0000b6700)\n\t/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2947 +0x30c\nnet/http.(*con"
}
```

BUT; this will *not* end up as a ERROR in [Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting):

```json
{
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "message": "hello error",
  "stack_trace": "fake stack trace"
}
```

NB: All the JSON messages here are pretty printed, it is important that the JSON you print in your app is on a single line to work with structured logging.

NB2: If you want your errors to be grouped by the service that made them you need to add `serviceContext`. E.g.

```json
"serviceContext":{"service":"service-name"}
```